# How can i delete part of an object insite another object?

Tags: modeling, blender-id

I am trying something in blender and i would like to delete this inner part of the orange object so the second object (grey) is open. How can i do this? [image]

Comment: Can you add some other photos of the model? I'm having a hard time understanding from the current angle. Besides that you might just want to use loop selection on the faces and then delete them, or select the outside invert and then delete the inside.

Comment: as  Nascent Space says your question is not clear, are you trying to make a sort of boolean of the yellow with the grey?